# Rename a file by searching for a reference in it then using that reference as the new file name

Tags: append, filenames, text-extraction, batch-rename

I have hundreds of technical drawing. Files (1 page A1 plans) and I want to name each one with  2 parts or references which are  found in the title block under

"drawing number"

And

"drawing name..."

I wish to combine the number and name to provide the new file reference /file name

I have never coded, but I am trying to research if this is even possible or viable as manually opening each drawimg, copying the name and then updating the file name seems to be crying out for automation